# DB2 in Docker results in DB21018E

Tags: docker, db2, dockerfile, db2-express-c

I can't build a Docker image with DB2.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ibmcom/db2express-c

EXPOSE 50000
CMD ["db2start"]

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN su - db2inst1 -c "db2 create db DMX"
```

Log:

```
Building image...
Step 1/5 : FROM ibmcom/db2express-c

 ---> 7aa154d9b73c


Step 2/5 : EXPOSE 50000

 ---> Using cache

 ---> 3172f8b3790b


Step 3/5 : CMD ["db2start"]

 ---> Using cache

 ---> f38e27452920


Step 4/5 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

 ---> Using cache

 ---> 1cef61dbf3c5


Step 5/5 : RUN su - db2inst1 -c "db2 create db DMX"

 ---> Running in 59b7a5d1c0ba


DB21018E  A system error occurred. The command line processor could not 
continue processing.

Error: ResponseItem.ErrorDetail[code=8,message=The command '/bin/bash -c su 
    - db2inst1 -c "db2 create db DMX"' returned a non-zero code: 8]
```

But if I execute `su - db2inst1 -c "db2 create db DMX"` manually it works:

```
MB-54:test mkadan$ docker exec -i -t db2 /bin/bash
[root@5cb934e6d434 /]# su - db2inst1 -c "db2 create db DMX"
DB20000I  The CREATE DATABASE command completed successfully.
```

Any hint what's the problem here?

Comment: My guess is that you don't have the DB2 environment set up inside the docker shell. You will need to import `/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile` (your path may be different, based on your install path). I'm not familiar with how you would do that in Docker.

Comment: Compare the db2diag entries for both cases (when it works interactively, versus when it fails when run via "su - db2inst1"). If necessary, set DIAGLEVEL 4 for the instance first (temporarily).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was indeed in bash environment not set up correctly. I resolved it by using the following `RUN` command:

`RUN su - db2inst1 -c "/bin/bash && db2start && db2 create db DMX"`

instead of the original one:

`RUN su - db2inst1 -c "db2 create db DMX"`