# DB2 Client in Docker

Tags: docker, db2

We have the need to create a docker container that also has the db2 client installed. This container will also have some shell scripts that make use of the db2 client.

We take a base Cent OS image and then add db2 via a RUN command:

```
COPY  db2rtcl_nr.rsp /db2install/
RUN cd /db2install && curl -o ibm_data_server_runtime_client_linuxx64_v11.1.tar.gz http://public_file_server.com/downloads/appTools/installs/db2/ibm_data_server_runtime_client_linuxx64_v11.1.tar.gz && \
tar -xvf ibm_data_server_runtime_client_linuxx64_v11.1.tar.gz && \
rm -f ibm_data_server_runtime_client_linuxx64_v11.1.tar.gz && \
rtcl/db2setup -u db2rtcl_nr.rsp -f sysreq && \

chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/ibm/db2/V11.1

ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1/bin"
```

The image builds ok with no errors.

However, when I try running and connecting to the container via interactive shell command:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash db2Container
```

and try to invoke the db2 CLI with

```
db2
```

I get the error:

> DB21018E  A system error occurred. The command line processor could not
>   continue processing.

Whats confusing is that if I immediately run a `bash` shell and then invoke the `db2` CLI, it works:

```
bash
db2
(c) Copyright IBM Corporation 1993,2007
Command Line Processor for DB2 Client 11.1.0

You can issue database manager commands and SQL statements from the command
prompt. For example:
db2 => connect to sample
db2 => bind sample.bnd

For general help, type: ?.
For command help, type: ? command, where command can be
the first few keywords of a database manager command. For example:
 ? CATALOG DATABASE for help on the CATALOG DATABASE command
 ? CATALOG          for help on all of the CATALOG commands.

To exit db2 interactive mode, type QUIT at the command prompt. Outside
interactive mode, all commands must be prefixed with 'db2'.
To list the current command option settings, type LIST COMMAND OPTIONS.

For more detailed help, refer to the Online Reference Manual.

db2 =>
```

Things I have tried to diagnose the issue:

1. When I 1st drop into the interactive shell session, I type
   `env > /tmp/env1.txt`
   I then type `bash` and run
   `env > /tmp/env2.txt`
   When I `diff` the files, they are virtually identical EXCEPT for the variable:
   `SHLVL=2`
   which I know is just indicating that the 2nd shell is a nested shell
2. When I 1st drop into the interactive shell session, I type
   `set > /tmp/set1.txt`
   I then type `bash` and run
   `set > /tmp/set2.txt`
   When I `diff` the files, they are virtually identical EXCEPT for the `SHLVL` variable again

Why is the db2 CLI accessible after I `bash` in the container but not in the initial session when i have used `docker run -it`?

We are attempting to use this container as an executable container that has the db2 client in it to connect to external DB2 databases.  We are NOT trying to run a db2 DB in a container.

What I am starting to find is that I might have an issue with how the entrypoint is defined in our Dockerfile.
Using:

```
ENTRYPOINT cat /dev/null && /usr/bin/bash
```

the DB2 client is available when I run `docker run -it ContainerName` without having to immediately type `bash`

BUT it does not work when I try to run the container as an executable `docker run ContainerName`

The closest I have come to the solution is this modification to the Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT []

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I run the container as an executable `docker run ContainerName db2 list command options` it works however NOW if I `docker run -it ContainerName` I dont immediately have `db2` commands available without typing `bash` once.  This is still problematic since this container will have shell script in it that need to be able to run db2 commands

Comment: Does it make a difference if you explicitly dot in the db2profile *before* you  run the CLP?   If it does, either the wrong startup profile is running, or that startup profile has'nt been properly updated, or is not running correctly.

Comment: @mao when you say "dot in the db2profile" do you mean source it?

Comment: If the login shell for the userid is either bash or ksh/ksh93 then `dot in` means the equivalent of `source` in csh. A default installation of the current V11.1.3.3b runtime client on linux with bash as the configured shell will automatically update the .bashrc with the relevant dot in command for the db2profile.

Comment: @bhamby I dont think this is exactly the same as [DB2 in Docker results in DB21018E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117273/db2-in-docker-results-in-db21018e) as they seem to be spinning up a db in their container and need to keep it running as a service. Whereas Im trying to use this container to execute some db2 client commands against an external DB.

Comment: @mao I dont think sourcing it helped. Same issue.  I'm starting to feel like this is an issue with how we have defined the entrypoint in the Dockerfile.  We have tried a few different setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more googling, I found this article: https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/01/dumb-init-an-init-for-docker.html

Using their [Github page](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/01/dumb-init-an-init-for-docker.html) example, I updated our Dockerfile with:

```
RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/dumb-init https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_amd64
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
```

and also updated our Dockerfile's entrypoint with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The result has been that my dummy shell script (that has a db2 command in it) that lives inside of the container works when the docker container is called as an executable:

```
docker run myContainer /scripts/dummyDB2connect.sh
```

AND I can also interactively spin up and connect to the container to run db2 commands without having to type the extra `bash` command.

Comment: Additional implementation of using an init tool to run as your initial entrypoint:
https://github.com/krallin/tini

Comment: OR this all could have been solved had I started the container with `--init`

But for the sake of not having to remember to always type that we're gonna leave the dumb init in the ENTRYPOINT

Comment: Hi @JuanD, might I have you Dockerfile please?

Comment: Hi @JuanD, can you share you Dockerfile with me also? Or share the github repo for this project. Thanks.